# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evaluate this integral:
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dxdydz$$
I coverted the region by using polar coordinate system for xy-plane and it became:
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}}r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\arctan{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}drd\theta dz+\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\arctan{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}drd\theta dz$$
After IBP
$$\int r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\arctan{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}dr=\frac{1}{3}(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\arctan{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}-\frac{1}{6}(r^2+z^2)+\frac{1}{6}\ln(r^2+z^2+1)+C $$ and replace upper and lower limits, it is scary-looking.
My experience in solving this tyle of integral is still weak, I think there is a way to get rid of one variable from the beginning integral, but i can't figure it out. Hope everyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Considering the use of a $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, I feel a shift to spherical (instead of polar/cylindrical) coordinates will be the way to go.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thank, can you give me a hint for the upper and lower limits when transform to spherical coordinates?

Comment: Increase the symmetry of the problem by going $-1$ to $1$ and divide by the symmetry factor at the end. [For the simpler problem with the integrand being indicator function for $r \leq R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074785/volume-of-sphere-cube-intersection)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Spherical coordinates are obviously the natural choice for the integrand, but a very unnatural choice for the region of integration. It’s not clear if the overall problem is any less difficult than where we started.

Comment: One can get a numerical approximation by dividing the unit cube
into N parts along each axis (N^3 smaller cubes) and using Rieman
sums. So for N=10, 20, 30, .., the numerical approximations are                                                      0.75752560813883478192
0.75855222922061113336
0.75874228522195874044
0.75880880046659419103
0.75883958675808790787
0.7588563099728932806

Comment: A seminumerical approach is to expand the integrand in a 
Taylor series around x=y=z=1/2, r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) like
r*arctan(r) = K/2+(2/7+K/3)*(x-1/2)+...
  +(44/147+2K/9)*(x-1/2)^2+(4/147-2K/9)*(x-1/2)*(y-1/2)+...
where .... means the obvious symmetric other terms by permutation of x,y and z, K=sqrt(3)*arctan(sqrt(3)/2).
These can be integrated term by term along x, y  and z. The values of expansions up to (total) Taylor orders of 4, 6, 8,10,..
are
0.76161153582438728,
0.75889140751595313,
0.75891201181166946,
0.75889044935636574,
0.75889272930661994,
0.75889516406780810.

Answer (score 10):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the definite integral in question:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right)}\approx0.758894.$$

The derivation below will show that

> $$\mathcal{I}=-\frac34-\frac{\pi^{2}}{48}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{8}+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}.$$

---

To begin, we can simplify this integral by taking advantage of its permutation symmetry, i.e., the integration intervals are the same for each variable and the integrand $f(x,y,z)$ is unchanged under any rearranging of $(x,y,z)$.

For any function $f(x,y,z)$ integrable over the unit cube and symmetric in its three variables, its integral can be split up into a sum of $3!=6$ parts as

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{x}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{x}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z).\\
\end{align}$$

After changing all the orders of integration and relabeling variables as needed, we find that these six integrals are in fact all equal to each other, i.e.,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z)=6\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,f(x,y,z).$$

---

Making use of the symmetry of $\mathcal{I}$, we can rewrite the triple integral as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right)}\\
&=6\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{symmetry}\\
&=6\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}u\,x^{3}\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}\arctan{\left(x\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[(y,z)=(xt,xu)\right]}\\
&=6\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{3}\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}\arctan{\left(x\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}\right)}\\
&=6\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)}}{\left(1+t^{2}+u^{2}\right)^{3/2}};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{6}{\left(1+t^{2}+u^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

The integration over $v$ in the last line above is in fact elementary, as can be seen by verifying the following derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dv}\left[v\left(3-v^{2}\right)+3\left(v^{4}-1\right)\arctan{\left(v\right)}\right]=12v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)};~~~\small{v\in\mathbb{R}}.$$

Transforming the outer double integral of $\mathcal{I}$ to polar coordinates, we can reduce the integral $\mathcal{I}$ to single-variable integrals as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{6}{\left(1+t^{2}+u^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+t^{2}+u^{2}}}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{\sec{\left(\theta\right)}}\mathrm{d}\rho\,\frac{6\rho}{\left(1+\rho^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+\rho^{2}}}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)};~~~\small{\left[\left(t,u\right)=\left(\rho\cos{\left(\theta\right)},\rho\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right)\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+\sec^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{6}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{3}\arctan{\left(v\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{1+\rho^{2}}=x\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+\sec^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{2x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{d}{dv}\left[v\left(3-v^{2}\right)+3\left(v^{4}-1\right)\arctan{\left(v\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+\sec^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{2x^{2}}\left[x\left(3-x^{2}\right)+3\left(x^{4}-1\right)\arctan{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{1}^{\sqrt{1+\sec^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{3}{x}-x+\frac{3\left(x^{4}-1\right)}{x^{2}}\arctan{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2+\tan^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[-x^{2}+2\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right)}+\frac{3+x^{4}}{x}\arctan{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\bigg{[}-x^{2}+2\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{3+x^{4}}{x}\arctan{\left(x\right)}\bigg{]};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\bigg{[}-\left(2+t^{2}\right)+2\ln{\left(\frac{3+t^{2}}{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{3+\left(2+t^{2}\right)^{2}}{\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}-\left(-1+\pi\right)\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\bigg{[}-\left(1+t^{2}\right)+2\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\pi\\
&~~~~~+\frac{7+4t^{2}+t^{4}}{\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}+2\ln{\left(1+\frac13t^{2}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t+\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{7+4t^{2}+t^{4}}{2\left(1+t^{2}\right)\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac13t^{2}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}\\
&=-\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac13t^{2}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Define the function $\mathcal{J}:\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}}{\left(b+t^{2}\right)\sqrt{a+t^{2}}},$$

define the function $\mathcal{K}:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\times\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{K}{\left(n,a\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(a+t^{2}\right)^{n-1/2}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)},$$

and define the function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$F{\left(b\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+b^{2}t^{2}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=-\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{2+t^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac13t^{2}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}\\
&=-\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}+2\mathcal{J}{\left(2,1\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\mathcal{K}{\left(0,2\right)}+\frac12\mathcal{K}{\left(1,2\right)}+F{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4313813/) by Ali Shadhar can be used (with slight modifications) to provide a closed-form expression for $F$:

$$F{\left(b\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(1+b\right)}-C+\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-b}{1+b}\right)};~~~\small{0<b},$$

where the inverse tangent integral $\operatorname{Ti}_{2}$ is defined by

$$\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{t};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}},$$

and the Catalan constant $C$ may be given be the integral representation

$$C:=\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(1\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{t}.$$

---

It is shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041358/) that $\mathcal{J}$ obeys the following functional relation:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\frac{\pi\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{(a+1)b}}\right)}}{2\sqrt{(a-b)b}}+\frac{\pi\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{(a+1)(a-b)}}\right)}}{2\sqrt{(a-b)b}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b}}\right)}\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)}}{\sqrt{(a-b)b}}-\mathcal{J}{\left(a,a-b\right)};~~~\small{0<b<a}.\\
\end{align}$$

This has the implication that

$$a\,\mathcal{J}{\left(a,\frac{a}{2}\right)}=\pi\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right)}-\arctan^{2}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\right)};~~~\small{0<a},$$

and in particular

$$2\,\mathcal{J}{\left(2,1\right)}=\pi\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}-\arctan^{2}{\left(1\right)}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{16}=\frac{5\pi^{2}}{48}.$$

---

The value of $\mathcal{K}{\left(1,a\right)}$ can be related to $\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}$ through the recurrence relation

$$2\mathcal{K}{\left(1,a\right)}=-1+\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{a+1}+a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)};~~~\small{0<a}.$$

*Proof*: Given $a>0$,

$$\begin{align}
2\mathcal{K}{\left(1,a\right)}
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2(a+t^{2})}{\sqrt{a+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{a+2t^{2}}{\sqrt{a+t^{2}}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=a\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{a+t^{2}}}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[t\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right]\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)}\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[t\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right]\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\frac{d}{dt}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t\sqrt{a+t^{2}}\,\frac{t}{\left(1+a+t^{2}\right)\sqrt{a+t^{2}}}\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+1}\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{2}}{1+a+t^{2}}\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+1}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[-1+\frac{1+a}{1+a+t^{2}}\right]\\
&=a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{a+1}\right)}-1+\sqrt{a+1}\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right)}\\
&=-1+\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{a+1}+a\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then, for $a>0$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{K}{\left(0,a\right)}
&=\mathcal{K}{\left(0,0\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{K}{\left(0,x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{t}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+t^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x+t^{2}}}\\
&=\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(1\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+t^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x+t^{2}}}\right]\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{2\left(1+x+t^{2}\right)\left(x+t^{2}\right)}-\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+t^{2}}\right)}}{2\left(x+t^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\right]\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)}}{2x\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)}\right]}{2x\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan{\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)}\right]}{x\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}\right)}}{x\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=C+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{a+1}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\arctan{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(y^{2}-1\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{x+1}=y\right]}\\
&=C+\int_{0}^{\frac{1-\sqrt{a+1}}{1+\sqrt{a+1}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{t};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right]}\\
&=C-\int_{0}^{\frac{-1+\sqrt{a+1}}{1+\sqrt{a+1}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{t};~~~\small{\left[t\mapsto-t\right]}\\
&=C-\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+1}-1}{\sqrt{a+1}+1}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it all together, we arrive finally at an expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of well-known constants and functions:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=-\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}+2\mathcal{J}{\left(2,1\right)}+\frac12\mathcal{K}{\left(0,2\right)}+\frac12\mathcal{K}{\left(1,2\right)}+F{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}\\
&=-\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}+\frac{5\pi^{2}}{48}-\frac14+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{8}+\mathcal{K}{\left(0,2\right)}+F{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}\\
&=-\frac34-\frac{\pi^{2}}{48}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{8}+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Oh my, such a wonderful attempt, thank you for posting these.

Comment: One may also look in to Ahmed' s Integral in Google.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way using symmetry.

Firstly denote $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and split the integrand
$$
I=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1r\arctan r~dV=\frac\pi2\underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1r~dV}_{I_1}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1r\operatorname{arccot} r ~dV}_{I_2}
$$
The former is the average distance from a point in a unit cube to the origin. Use its symmetry to split the cube into 6 parts, in each of which the integral is identical. Substitute $p=xz,q=yz$ in one of them and perform the easy integral over $z$
$$
I_1=6\int_0^1\int_0^z\int_0^y\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz\\
=6\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1z^3\sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}dpdqdz=\frac32\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}dpdq
$$
Now switch to polar coordinate $(p,q)\to (\rho,\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
&I_1=\frac32\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}dpdq
\\ =&\frac32\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sec\theta}\sqrt{\rho^2+1}~\rho d\rho d\theta
\\ =&\frac12\int_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\cdot\int_0^{\sec\theta}\frac32\sqrt{\rho^2+1}~d(\rho^2+1)
\\ =&\frac12\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}^3}{\cos^3\theta}-1~d\theta
\\ =&\frac12\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \theta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{\sin\theta~\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}}{2\cos^2\theta }\right.
\\&\left.\left.+\log \left(\frac{1+\sin\theta\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}}{\cos^2\theta}\right)\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}-\frac\pi8
\\ =&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi}{24}+\frac12\log \left(2+\sqrt3\right)
\end{align}
$$
The last integral has an elementary antiderivative and can be evaluated quickly substituting $s=\sin\theta$.

By the identity $\displaystyle\operatorname{arccot}\lambda=\int_0^1\frac{\lambda ~dw}{\lambda^2+w^2}$ and the symmetry of the latter
$$
\begin{align}
&I_2=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1r\cdot\left(\int_0^1\frac{r~dw}{w^2+r^2}\right)dV
\\ =&\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}dxdydzdw
\\ =&3\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}dxdydzdw
\\ =&\frac34\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}dxdydzdw
\\ =&\frac34
\end{align}
$$
Combining the results above and the desired integral follows
$$
I=\frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{8}-\frac{\pi ^2}{48}+\frac{\pi}{4}   \log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)-\frac34
$$

Comment: Well that’s certainly quicker… +1

Answer (score 3):

Very similar steps from **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, pages **261**-**261**, can be applied where there we have that

$$\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y$$ $$=\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y.$$

Similarly, we have that
$$\int_0^1  \left( \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{dz}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}\textrm{d}w\right)\textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y,$$
where since the last quadruple integral is immediately done by symmetry, the rest of the work to do is straightforward in various ways.